# Calculate percentile of a value, given only the 25th, 50th and 75th percentile

Tags: excel, percentile

This may or may not be the correct forum to post this question to BUT I'm hoping for the best.

Currently, we are trying to calculate what percentile a given salary value is based on the 25th, 50th and 75th percentile for each position in our company. I'm not sure how to go about this given only three data points (25th, 50th and 75th percentiles for each position).

For example, we are paying Employee A $72k/year and the data for this position is: $66k (25th percentile), $72k (50th percentile) and 80k (75th percentile). Clearly, employee A's salary is in the 50th percentile. There are many employees whose salaries do not line up as nicely, so if anyone has an idea how to solve for the percentiles for other salary amounts, I would greatly appreciate it!

I've been trying to create a formula to calculate the percentiles for each salary and have fail miserably so far... Is there a way to do this? Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

This is a **horiible**,*horrible* kludge, but it gets you some info... Note I haven't taken into account items past 0% and 100%

I put the value I am testing in A1
I put the 25th,50th and 75th percentile in B1,B2 & B3

The formula I used was

```
=IF(A1<$B$2,0.5+((A1-$B$2)/($B$2-$B$1)/4),0.5+((A1-$B$2)/($B$3-$B$2))/4)
```

What this does is assume the 25->50 percentile range is the same as the 0% to 25% range, and the 75% to 100% percentile is the same as 50% to 75%.

Without other data like standard deviation, number of samples, and other fun statistics, this is a very bad approximation at best, and no better than rolling dice at worst.